# Security risks of Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Tags: typescript, powershell, npm, npm-scripts

To execute some commands like `installing typescript` via `NPM`, Sometimes it is needed to execute :

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

in PowerShell, When you want change this policy, it warns that :

> Changing the execution policy might expose you to the security risks

My question is, anyone knows what are the security risks of doing such an action? is there any chance that famous packages like typescript  leads to security problems?

Answer (score 6):

There is very little risk involved with RemoteSigned, Basically this lets you execute unsigned scripts (scripts you write) only in local computer, while scripts from a remote source (From internet) must be signed by a trusted authority. The only security risk is that someone might write malicious script on your local computer and you execute it without knowing what is it. This is the most **recommended**. Default on Server editions.

And Unrestricted in highly insecure, letting you to run unsigned scripts from any source. This is **not recommended**.

And **Restricted** is too annoying, signed scripts even could not run, only interactive sessions. This is default on desktop editions.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell execution policies are made, more to avoid a wrong script execution by error, than for security purposes.

Remember the Bypass ExecutionPolicy who does not care about execution policies. The only way to block this, is to block it by group policies.

But even with it, user who wants to execute a script can always do it. Try the above code in an environment lab where you have blocked scripts by group policy, then run this code in PowerShell, do not exit PowerShell and try to run any script, it will run :

```
$context = $ExecutionContext.GetType().GetField('_context', 'NonPublic, Instance').GetValue($ExecutionContext)
$field = $context.GetType().GetField('_authorizationManager', 'NonPublic, Instance')
$field.SetValue($context, (New-Object System.Management.Automation.AuthorizationManager 'Microsoft.PowerShell'))
```

It is a long time that malwares use PowerShell, whatever are the execution policies.

So as Wasif said, you can use RemoteSigned without any remorse ;)